# Magento & .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I've spent the best part of this afternoon trying to figure out why my .htaccess file isn't working as expected.  Basically what I wanted to do was add url rewrites to map old urls to new ones. So I created all my rewrites and pasted them into the .htaccess file, they worked in the sense that the pattern was matched and the server redirected, but it was always redirected to the directory path as in `domain.com/var/www/docroot/.../tools.html` I thought this might be as a result of `RewriteBase` being commented out and the root document not being set properly elsewhere, I don't have access to the main configuration files as this is a shared server.  So I uncommented the `RewriteBase /` and the redirects worked as expected.  The problem is when I try to navigate to the sitemap I get a 404 error, the sitemap is definitely there.  Since then I have tried all sorts of things, I think I have narrowed the issue down to the

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

Whilst reading allsorts of stuff online and trying to understand the apache docs, I came accross something that said Rewrite Conditions only apply to the Rule immediately following it.  So I tried adding the above Rewrite Conditions again jut before the index.php bootstrap section, doing this lets me get my sitemap, but when I try to load the home page I get a default Plesk control panel page, if I comment out the `RewriteBase /` my home page loads but the sitemap url tries to load domain.com/var/www/.../sitemap.xml.  I'm confused and my head hurts now, I have been trying to find an answer all afternoon...  I would appreciate any suggestions.

Here's the file:

```
    ############################################
    ## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
    ## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
    ## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

    #    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
    #    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

    ############################################
    ## GoDaddy specific options

    #   Options -MultiViews

    ## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
    ##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
    ## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

    ############################################
    ## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

        #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
        #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

    ############################################
    ## default index file

        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>

    ############################################
    ## adjust memory limit

    #    php_value memory_limit 64M
        php_value memory_limit 256M
        php_value max_execution_time 18000

    ############################################
    ## disable magic quotes for php request vars

        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

    ############################################
    ## disable automatic session start
    ## before autoload was initialized

        php_flag session.auto_start off

    ############################################
    ## enable resulting html compression

        #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

    ###########################################
    # disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

        php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

    ###########################################
    # turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

        php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_security.c>
    ###########################################
    # disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

        SecFilterEngine Off
        SecFilterScanPOST Off
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    ############################################
    ## enable apache served files compression
    ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

        # Insert filter on all content
        ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        # Insert filter on selected content types only
        #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
        #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

        # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
        #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

        # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
        #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # Don't compress images
        #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>

    ############################################
    ## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

        SSLOptions StdEnvVars

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    ############################################
    ## enable rewrites

        Options +FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine on

    ############################################
    ## you can put here your magento root folder
    ## path relative to web root

        RewriteBase /

    ############################################
    ## workaround for HTTP authorization
    ## in CGI environment

        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    ############################################
    ## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/


    ############################################
    ## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


    ############################################
    ## old url rewrites

        RewriteRule .*_57581_pd\.asp tools.html [R=302,L]


    ############################################
    ## rewrite everything else to index.php
    ## 

        RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

    </IfModule>


    ############################################
    ## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
    ## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

        AddDefaultCharset Off
        #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    <IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ############################################
    ## Add default Expires header
    ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

    </IfModule>

    ############################################
    ## By default allow all access

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

    ###########################################
    ## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

        <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </Files>

    ############################################
    ## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
    ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

        #FileETag none
```

In the complete file there are lots of these types of rewrites `RewriteRule .*_57581_pd\.asp tools.html [R=302,L]`, but there are too many to paste here so I have removed all but 1 for reference.

Comment: Why don't you use Magento's built in URL rewrite functionality rather than hard-coding in URLS into your .htaccess file?  Is it because you require a wildcard url redirect?

Comment: @Axel No, I could have built a list of full urls and remapped them, but I assumed doing redirects at server level would be faster/more efficient.  Also it was quicker/easier and I can easily get rid of them in the future when the indexes have been updated.  There's 24,000 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing this rule to:

```
RewriteRule .*_57581_pd\.asp http://%{HTTP_HOST}/tools.html [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I was going to post a long comment about how I had considered something like that earlier and why I didn't do it.  But my head hurts enough as it is, so i'll try it and report back.

Comment: No didn't work, it does redirect the above rule to the right page but with `RewriteBase /` uncommented they work anyway.  It's my sitemap that wont load, I just tried commented `RewriteBase /` out again and using your code above for my rewrites, but my sitemap still 404's.

Comment: @4D1 that's really weird, for some reason it keeps thinking that they're all file-path URI's as opposed to URL-paths, I guess the other thing you can try is leaving the base in, then adding a `/` in front of each of the `/tools.html` and `/index.php` to try to convince apache that you're dealing with URL-paths.

Comment: Yea, it's got me climbing the walls, but i'm not sure if i'm explaining myself properly, so to try and reiterate concisely...  With `RewriteBase /` commented redirects are treated as file path URI's and my sitemap.xml 404's.  With `RewriteBase /` uncommented my redirects are treated as URL paths but my sitemap.xml still 404's.  If I move/copy the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` directives to just above the `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]` then my sitemap loads, my redirects work but mydomain.com loads a plesk page unless I navigate to mydomain.com/index.php

Comment: @4D1 How about instead of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, you try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sitemap\.html`?

Comment: no still not working...  my sitemap is in a directory sm, so i tried `!sitemap\.xml !.*sitemap\.xml - !sm/sitemap\.xml`.

Comment: It's even weirder because images, css and js files all load just fine, the rules are obviously working for them.  But an xml file just won't, unless i move the ! f,d,l to just above bootstrap...